# What kind of Distribution is this?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I think the question is asking to find a probability distribution for a discrete random variable. But I am not entirely positive because it asks to determine the sample space, but assign probabilities to each outcome.

A game is played 10 times. The chance of a big prize is .1, small prize is .3 and no prize is .6.

**What is the sample space. How does one denote the outcomes? How does one assign probabilities to each outcome.**

For one game, there are three outcomes. So for ten games, there are $3^10$ ways. I would denote the outcomes as B, S, N for big, small, and nothing. (This question seems pretty arbitrary, unless it is about a distribution. Same goes for the question about the distribution, I get .1, .3, and .6 respectively.

Now I have some other questions involving general probability stuff involving the question.

**Find the prob of winning exactly 2 big and 3 small in 10 games.**

I said this was  $(.1^2)(.3^3)(.6^5)$

**How many different configurations of numbers of big, small, and nothing are possible in 10 games?**

Isn't this the same as the sample space, $3^{10}$? If not then how else would one think about this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For positive outcomes you are taking the ordering of when the prizes are won into consideration. For this question it seems like you shouldn't do that, at least for the second part since you are taking your sample space to be all orderings of how prizes can be won. Use multinomial coefficients to correct for this.

Also, for the second question, if you are taking a fixed ordering of how the prizes are won and then calculating for example $2 \cdot 0.1$ when it should be $0.1^2$

Comment: good call for the second question. whoops

Answer (score 0):

The outcomes consist of all ordered 10-tuples drawn from the set $\{B,S,N\}$.  So for example, $$(B,B,B,S,S,S,N,N,N,N)$$ is one such outcome, for which the $k^{\rm th}$ prize won is denoted by the $k^{\rm th}$ entry in the ordered list; thus, the above is a distinct outcome from $$(B,S,N,B,S,N,B,S,N,N)$$ even though the number of each type of outcome is the same in both--$(B,S,N) = (3,3,4)$.

We might write the sample space as $$\mathcal S = \{(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{10}) : x_i \in \{B,S,N\} \forall i = 1, 2, \ldots, 10\}.$$

If $\boldsymbol X = (X_1, X_2, X_3)$ represents a vector-valued random variable that counts the number of big, small, and non-prizes obtained, then $\boldsymbol X$ follows a **multinomial distribution** with parameters $p_1 = 0.1$, $p_2 = 0.3$, $p_3 = 0.6$ and $N = 10$.  Specifically, this is a *trinomial* distribution (i.e., the number of categories is $m = 3$).

The probability distribution for the general multinomial case is given by $$\Pr[\boldsymbol X = \boldsymbol x] = \frac{N!}{x_1! x_2! \ldots x_m!} p_1^{x_1} p_2^{x_2} \ldots p_m^{x_m},$$ where $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m)$ is the ordered $m$-tuple of observed counts among the $m$ categories.